# React-Native-Navigation TabNavigator screen change function?

Tags: react-native, navigation, tabnavigator

I'm using the react-native-navigation tab navigator in my app, and on one of my screens I have a button where you can play music. If you press the button and then navigate to a different screen (using the tab bar) however, the music continues to play. I'm trying to find a way to make the music stop when the user navigates to another screen.

Is there something similar to a componentDidUnmount() method that I can call when the screen changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options here (that I'm aware of), neither great.

First, you can [use Redux to to manage your navigator's state](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/guides/redux) and, when tabs change, listen to that change and when the relevant tab is no longer active stop playing the music.

Second, you could try using [`onNavigationStateChange`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/guides/screen-tracking) but this feels really hacky to me - and I'm not sure how well it would actually work.

Comment: Yeah I couldn't figure out how to use the onNavigationStateChange in this situation. Looks like redux it is! Thanks for your input

Answer (score 4):

Starting on [v1.0.0-beta.28](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/releases/tag/v1.0.0-beta.28), you can now subscribe in your screens to some tab events (willFocus, didFocus, willBlur, didBlur):

```
componentDidMount() {
this._sub = this.props.navigation.addListener(
    'willFocus',
    this.yourCallback
  );
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this._sub.remove();
}
```

More details here: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/pull/3345